# How to constraint DraftJs editor input to single line?

Tags: typescript, draftjs

I want want to use DraftJs in Typescript to make two Editor components: one for an email subject and one for an email body.

**My problem**: Because an email subject can only be 1 line, I want to constrain the Editor component input for the subject to also be one line.

I started by swallowing the enter command (split-block), but a user could simply paste multi-line text to get around that.

Comment: Apparently, there's a plugin called "[single-line-plugin](https://github.com/icelab/draft-js-single-line-plugin)". It's old, but if it's unusable then you could at least take a look at what they're doing.